# How to control databases replicated by Mongo DB replica set

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, replica-set

I have 2 databases in my mongo DB namespace, lets name them **db1**, **db2** and **db3** which are on the same dbpath.
Is it possible to configure mongo db replica set in that way that **db3** wont be replicated across secondaries?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, to the best of my knowledge this is not possible. A replica set member is identified by a hostname and port, and there are no settings to control which databases are included. See [Replica Set Configuration](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/) in the MongoDB manual.

You could create a separate MongoDB server instance configured on a different port (and using a different dbpath) to hold the **db3** data, although this would obviously complicate your server setup.

Comment: I was afraid that this might work like this - as I did not find anything in manuals.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB replication is handled by host and port, which is per-mongod-process.

The way to do this would be to run db3 run in another mongod process, which runs on a different tcp port.